# Create circuit with triggered light and simultaneous output to computer

Tags: circuit-design, switching, light

I'm doing an experiment and will be collecting voltage data (from strain gauges) which will be inputted to a computer through a conditioning system.

I would also like to collect video footage of the experiment, and be able to synchronize the video footage to the data.

My idea is to have a trigger/button/switch which is connected both to the data acquisition hardware (which can receive as input differential voltage signals) and also to a light. Therefore, when I press the trigger, a signal will be recorded along with my data and I can align this with the point in the video footage when the light turns on.

I'm wondering what this circuit would look like, and how to incorporate a light in it.

Comment: could you be just slightly more specific than "experiment", "data". Obviously, a way of inserting a synchronization signal in your measured signal depends on what you actually measure, and how. Please **edit** your question to include what you're measuring, and how you're measuring it.

Comment: So far, the circuit will have a lamp and a switch... You really need to specify (1) how the camera can be operated (what signals does it accept so it will start/stop recording) and (2) what signals the computer does accept/measure in order to detect the switch being pushed.

Comment: Thank you! This makes it a lot easier :)

Comment: Um, how often will you record one strain gauge data point (sampling rate? Or just at certain events?)

Comment: I don't want to insert a synchronization signal in my measured signal. I merely want both signals (data and switch) to be processed by the same hardware so that they are synchronized.

Comment: I'm thinking that I can manually press the trigger/switch and the recording button on the camera

Comment: it is unclear why you are able to read an input from a strain gauge, but you are unable to detect a switch closure

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Industry standard solution. Source: http://Rakuten.com.*

You could consider making a clapboard and this may be of use synchronising the audio too. For the data connection you can add a switch or make one by pinning stranded wire to the moving and fixed halves of the clapboard so that the circuit is closed when the board is closed.

If you really want a light then add a second switch contact.

Comment: I do not think that a clapboard is a good solution here. You can add a switch to it, to get a timestamp on the computer, but then how do you measure how open is the clapboard when the switch trips? Depending on OP synch requirements, and depending on the switch used, the delay between the switch and a known position of the trap can vary with the closing speed, which is certainly undesirable.

Comment: I think it might be good – if Isabela takes one sample every 5 minutes, 10ms of timing error is probably totally irrelevant. If, on the other hand, she needs data every 1 ms …

Comment: 10 ms is too high

Comment: @Vladimir: The video is only going to have in the region of 25 frames per second. I would imagine that the arm is moving at about 360°/s at the time of impact giving 14°/frame.

Comment: @Isabela: What is your video frame rate?

Comment: @Isabela in case you don't understand why we're asking this: If 10 ms of timing accuracy isn't good enough (I take it that's what you meant when you said "too high"), then you need a high-speed camera to get the same temporal resolution from your video. Assuming you use a 60 fps camera, then your maximum bandwidth that it can alias-free capture is 30 Hz, meaning your temporal resolution is 33 ms, best case.